# Returning Total No of Records in @RequestParam in spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/states/{countrycode}", method = 
RequestMethod.GET )
    public Service getStates(@PathVariable ("countrycode") String 
countrycode,@RequestParam(value = "count", required = false, defaultValue = 
"10") Integer count)
```

In this case my problem is i don't want to set default value to certain count,

If user will pass count then it should return that many number of records and it is returning ,but when user is not passing any count it should return all the record from db,but its not working  this is my service return logic `return modelststelist.subList(0, count);` here count is coming from  method as parameter in my service.

Comment: "but its not working" What is the error?

Comment: Don't use `sublist` imho very bad, use your database query to limit the results in stead. If you are using a sublist you are basically retrieving everything, then only return x items. So if you have 10000 rows you first get all of them, then return only the first x rows. Very inefficient.

Comment: Actuallty this record is not comung from db it is coming from some other services in json format –

Answer (score 4):

In your case, remove  `required = false, defaultValue = "10"`

add like this,

```
public Service getStates(@PathVariable ("countrycode") String 
countrycode,@RequestParam(value = "count") Integer count)
```

Pass the count to backend, get the details and return it

Comment: in this case i am making required = false because this is not mandatory for user to pass if they don't pass then i have to return total records from db ,but it is practically not possibe to know every time hoe may records are there in db

Comment: check the count value if not null (if(count!=null){codehere}) get the details from db and return it. otherwise, if count value is null, return all the records related to that user...